# Object Property Change Does Not Cause Rerender in React-Native

Tags: react-native, state

I am currently developing a simple accounting app. I have read data from a local sqlite table and rendered an initial list. Database is saved in state as an array of objects.
I have implemented a pull to refresh function which reads the sms and update the database (set acknowledged = 1) if transaction id matches with one in the DB. However, when I modify database and try to re render my ui, it does not rerender. It only renders when i force close my app and re open it.
Here is the short code.

```
class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      refreshing: false,
    };
    this.baseState = this.state;
    console.log('initial state');
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table_accounts', [], (tx, results) => {
        var temp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
          temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
        this.setState({
          data: temp,
        });
        console.log('next state');
        console.log(this.state.data);
      });
    });
  }
```

```
 readSms = () => {
    var filter = {
      box: 'inbox',
      bodyRegex: '(.*)(?i)ok.(?-i)(.*)',
    //   address: this.state.accountReceiver,
    };

    console.log('reading sms');
    // this.resetState();

    SmsAndroid.list(
      JSON.stringify(filter),
      (fail) => {
        console.log('Failed with this error: ' + fail);
      },
      (count, smsList) => {
        var arr = JSON.parse(smsList);
        arr.forEach(function (object) {
          let data, tid;
          data = object.body.toString();
          tid = data.match(/\b\d{6}\b/g);
          let newTid = parseInt(tid.toString());
          db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table_accounts');
            tx.executeSql(
              `UPDATE table_accounts SET acknowledged=1 WHERE transactionId=${newTid}`,
              [],
            );
          });
        });
      },
    );

    this.getData();
  };

  _onRefresh() {
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    this.readSms();
    wait(2000).then(() => this.setState({refreshing: false}));
    }
```

```
  renderTable() {
    const data = this.state.data;

    return (
      <Block flex={0.2}>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <Block style={styles.grid} key={item.transactionId}>
            <Grid>
              <Col size={10} style={styles.column}>
                <Row style={styles.row}>
                  {item.acknowledged ? (
                    <Checkbox
                      disabled={true}
                      initialValue={true}
                      color="Success"
                      label=""
                      checkboxStyle={{
                        borderColor: '#adb5bd ',
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        width: 16,
                        height: 16,
                      }}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <Checkbox
                      color="Warning"
                      disabled={true}
                      label=""
                      checkboxStyle={{
                        borderColor: '#adb5bd ',
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        width: 16,
                        height: 16,
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                </Row>
              </Col>
              <Col size={60} style={styles.nameColumn}>
                <Row style={styles.row}>
                  <Text p bold size={14} color="black">
                    {item.accountReceiverName}
                  </Text>
                </Row>
              </Col>
              <Col size={30} style={styles.amountColumn}>
                <Row style={styles.row}>
                  <Text p size={13} color="black">
                    {item.amount}
                  </Text>
                </Row>
              </Col>
              <Col size={30} style={styles.deptColumn}>
                <Row style={styles.row}>
                  <Text p size={13} color="black">
                    {item.remarks}
                  </Text>
                </Row>
              </Col>
            </Grid>
          </Block>
        ))}
      </Block>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON.stringify() like

**Initial state like this**

```
this.state = {
   data: '',
   refreshing: false,
 };
```

**when you change state like this**

```
 this.setState({
   data: JSON.stringify(temp),
 });
```

**when you use data state**

```
JSON.parse(data).map((item) => (

))
```

hope so it will help you